# Dealing with flutter and google play games

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-play-games, google-play-console

Is there any body success sign in Google games with flutter?
I linked Google Play console with Firebase and flutter app, and the link success,
sha1, sha256, clientId, appId is also OK,
but I always get:
Unexpected error Status{statusCode=unknown status code: 12501, resolution=null
when sign in Google games using library game_services

GamesServices.signIn();

Answer (score 0):

12501 means USER_CANCELLED. Ref: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInStatusCodes

Which likely means that the sign-in activity fails to show properly or got dismissed prematurely. You may want to check that google play games app is up-to-date on your test device.